# How to store sessionFactory object in context and used same object whole application

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

I am developing application based on hibernate, but now in my application I am creating sessionFactory object per user i.e. while user is logged in which not right way.
I search lots on for same issue but I am not able find any solution on it. I read lots of on jndi but still not positive result.
I got same solution on it but they are using struts or spring but I need only hibernate application
Is anyone having the code or for sharing one sessionFactory object for **ALL USERS**.

I am using -

1. Tomcat server
2. Hibernate 4.0
3. NetBean

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach can be to create a listener like this:

```
public class HibernateContext implements ServletContextListener {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        sessionFactory.close();     
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Declare it on your web.xml:

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>yourpackage.HibernateContext</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and then, call the factory from anywhere in your code:

```
HibernateContext.getSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Thanks Alberto for reply ...But my concern is only that i want to add my sessionFactory in one common place where i can serv the same object to all user.without creating new sessionFactory to each user which is currently i am doing and whuch is wrong approach.

Comment: Are you using Spring or CDI/EJB? Because an approach can be declare an application context object where you can get the sessionFactory

Comment: No I am not using CDI/EJB? I am using only hibernate,servlate,jsp,tomCat.

Comment: So it's better if you use a Servlet Context Listener in additional with a util class containing the ThreadLocal, you will be able to "inject" and use the sessionFactory into your servlet using this approach

Comment: Yes Alberto ...i tried this ThreadLocal approach but i am not able to do that and also tried Servlet Context Listener but both was not able to implement .Did u have any example of this it will really very helpful for me ? ..Thanks in advanced

Comment: I've edited my answer, I think that this approach can solve your problem

Comment: Yes Alberto ..your solution is work for me and thank you very much for instant reply ;)